# How to implement on one method of TextWatcher in android?

Tags: android, android-textwatcher

I have an app in which i have lots of edit text but in some edit text i only want to implement only one method of TextWatcher. How do i do that kindly guide.

code:-

```
private TextWatcher m_textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        isFieldsEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        m_mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int heightDiff = m_mainLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - m_mainLayout.getHeight();
                if (!(heightDiff > RewardUtil.dpToPx(mContext, 200))) { // if more than 200 dp, it's probably a keyboard...
                    m_otpEditText.clearFocus();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
 m_otpEditText.addTextChangedListener(m_textWatcher);
```

Comment: Do you need to do perform action on text change in multiple editexts?

Comment: no i need to implement only one method of textwatcher not whole

Answer (score 2):

Create metod lke this.

```
   public static class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private EditText mEditText;

        public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
            mEditText = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            oldText = mEditText.toString();
        }
        ....
    }
```

And use like this...

```
  m_otpEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(mFirstEditText));
```

It will help you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can create a class as follows :

```
public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

Thereafter, just override the method/s you need. Suppose you need only onTextChanged method, then you can do as follows :

```
m_otpEditText.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

TextWatcher class gives you flexibility to override methods whichever you need. If you really need only one method then override only one, but you have to always implement all methods .